# Regex searching for time doesn't want to be non-greedy

Tags: regex, quantifiers, non-greedy, spiceworks

I'm trying to run a regex in Spiceworks to parse through email headers to select the first instance of time for ticket assignment purposes. **The regex itself works, but it picks up all instances of time rather than just one.**

Here's the regex: `\.*(0[1]|1[3-7]):\d\d:\d\d`

I've tried to make in non-greedy by doing this: `\.*?(0[1]|1[3-7]):\d\d:\d\d`
but that doesn't seem to work. Putting the question mark in front of a quantifier didn't do anything for this purpose.

What is a good solution to make this regex non-greedy or pick up only the first instance?

Thanks,

Andrew N.

Edit: What I'm trying to achieve from the regex is something like "13:04:57" instead of the whole date.

Sample string:
Received: by 127.0.0.1 with SMTP id co5csp22954317qdb; Wed, 6 May 2015 13:02:22 -0700 (PDT) X-Received: by 127.0.0.1 with SMTP id j185mr26699743oig.68.1430928141923; Wed, 06 May 2015 13:02:21 -0700 (PDT)

Comment: can you post some sample data to play with?

Comment: Please add these sample strings to the question and add expected output. Also,  does `((?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]).*` help? Just grab the contents of the first capturing group.

Comment: stribizhev - that one still returns two matches (in that snip of header).

Comment: @user3761389: My regex above will return the whole string after the time, but the value is inside a capturing group.

Comment: I must have been using a different regex tester. I see what you mean now. Looks like also does what I am after. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex to match first instance of the time matched by your regex:

```
/^(?:(?!(?:0[1]|1[3-7]):\d\d:\d\d).)*((?:0[1]|1[3-7]):\d\d:\d\d)/m
```

`(?!...)` is a negative lookahead that makes sure there is no other instance of time before matching a time thus matching only first instance.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yN8eW8/1)

Comment: Also, how would you start parsing from the very first instance of this? I noticed that I was taking further down the page a time from some other area (that would have matched the regex: Received: by (ip) with SMTP id (id);
        Wed, 6 May 2015 08:58:05 -0700 (PDT)

Comment: `08:58:05` should match in that line also. You can play with my demo link and provide a sample data there.

Answer (score 0):

{1} is match the previous pattern 1 time. If you post a sample header I could test the REGEX to ensure I am getting everything correct. Try the following.

```
(.*(0[1]|1[3-7]):\d\d:\d\d){1}
```